# About Custom validator for name field

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am Soft. Trainee.

I want to write  a custom validator for Name field.

It should only include characters and space.

Please specify the code so that I can understand it well.

Kindly help.

Comment: First tell us what you have tried??

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't very well defined so excuse me if I've taken it wrongly, but I'll have a go.

I would suggest a Regular expression validator (and maybe also add a Required Field Validator if the field is also required).

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server"
     Text="Name isn't Valid"
     ControlToValidate="nameTextBox" 
     ValidationExpression="^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

You may want to change the Expression to a more valid one for your situation, and obviously ensure the `ControlToValidate` points to the correct `Textbox`.